# How to click all images on the page at once using Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug, jquery, xpath

I have a page with a lot of images, each of them being wrapped with an onclick event. For example:

```
<a onclick=javascript:xxx(y,z)><img id="myclass" src="yyy"></a>
```

Following command returns all the images correctly:

```
$x("//img")
```

This doesn't (returns null):

```
$("img")
```

I assume, because these img tags were created dynamically, so are not directly in the source.

My idea was to add .click() at the end, but somehow it doesn't work.

---

So the question is:

How do I simulate clicking all images at once to trigger all associated javascript functions?

Comment: Also FYI, I just updated your post which had indicated "onlick" instead of "onclick".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `.click()` on collection as it is just a container for some objects and it doesn't have any methods from objects inside. You need to iterate over each object and call `.click()` individually:

```
for (var idx = document.images.length - 1; idx >= 0; idx--){ document.images[idx].click() }
```

I've just ran it in console and opened your profile and ad on sidebar.